# Plugin for automated upgrade of WordPress core and it's plugins?

Tags: updates, cron, automation

**Is it possible to get your WordPress site to upgrade itself automatically?**

What I mean is, when plugins etc. needs to be upgraded, can you just press a button, or have a cron job, download the new update and handle whatever else is needed, so your WordPress site always is up to date?

Comment: He was asking for an automatic update and it seems like all answers require manual upgrade.

Comment: Such feature is available since WordPress 3.7+ (http://codex.wordpress.org/Updating_WordPress#Automatic_Background_Updates)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the most recent version of WordPress, there are two ways you can update your plugins by just clicking a button (OK, maybe a couple, but it's still really easy).

Under *Dashboard* in your WP admin, there will an *Updates* option. Click on that and you should see something like this:

[image]

Choose *Select All* and then click *Update Plugins* and the system will do it for you.

I would advise against updating plugins totally automatically (as in without clicking any buttons yourself). It's important to check out the change log on the plugin's page and also its compatability with whatever version of WP you're running. For example, if you're running  2.8 you might upgrade automatically without checking only to find out that the latest version of the plugin isn't backward compatible with your WP install and requires WP 3.0.1.

The other way to update your plugins is to go to the Plugins page in the admin, sort by *Upgrade Available*, check the plugins compatibility and change log, select *Upgrade Automatically* and then reactivate the plugin when the process is done upgrading the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

> when plugins etc. needs to be upgraded, can you just press a button

**Yes.** WordPress supports one-click upgrading for plugins, themes, and WordPress itself.

Comment: You can see what updates are available by going to Dashboard >> Updates.  You can also do updates of plug-ins in bulk (update several plug-ins at once).  The system also supports theme updates as well.

Answer (score 0):

Hi **@googletorp** - I believe it would be possible to code a plugin to do what you ask, but the likelihood it would cause your site to crash gets more likely the more plugins you have. Better to update the site and plugins yourself and see it crash if it is going to do so than to have it auto-update and crash, and then not know for hours or days that it has crashed.

Given that, would you still want this?