# A Way to Auto update plugins using cron?

Tags: plugins, updates, upgrade, automation

Is there a solution to keep plugins updated with wordpress by auto upgrade them without need to access to the admin panel every time?

Answer (score 2):

Holy schmoly shadowpress - what a risky idea.

I imagine one could write a cron plugin to do it, BUT what a risk....Already the auto wordpress multi update feature makes it way too tempting to just hit the update button on a bunch of updates in one go.

Recommended 'safe' procedure for system upgrades is something along the lines of:
1) read the changelogs and test all upgrades on a local similar install first
2) make a backup before upgrading
3) apply updates individually, checking all is fine in between, possibly even making a new backup in between so you can rollback  should an upgrade not agree with your site.

If one can cope with the fallout of an error one could skip a step... but going to full automated update sounds like a recipe for disaster.

Consider the likelihood/risk/impact balance:

eg: the likelihood of a tsunami causing a nuclear reactor to melt down may be low, but the impact if it does......

Given that plugins are written by a variety of 3rd party developers, theres is a strong likeihood of a clash of some kind.   Also some plugins release major new features in an update and that sometimes requires human intervention.

That said - a look at the 'related' questions will show you that the question does come up now and then.
eg:
[Real automated and unattended wordpress upgrade including plugins](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2780/real-automated-and-unattended-wordpress-upgrade-including-plugins)

[Plugin for automated upgrade of WordPress core and it's plugins?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/933/plugin-for-automated-upgrade-of-wordpress-core-and-its-plugins)